# AWS S3 - How to get credentials correct for Android?

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, credentials

I am making an Android app with S3 so that user can upload stuff to S3 server. For AWS tokens, we use our own server to get the followings.

AwsToken.java is a POJO for the following json.

```
{
  "id": "us-east-1:xxxxx",
  "token": "xxxxx",
  "region": "us-east-1",
  "identityPoolId": "us-east-1:xxxxx",
  "loginProvider": "xxxxx"
}
```

Then I am trying to use this to create identityProvider and credentialsProvider to get AmazonS3Client and TransferUtility.

```
KOIAWSAuthenticatedIdentityProvider identityProvider = new KOIAWSAuthenticatedIdentityProvider(awsToken);

CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider cognitoCachingCredentialsProvider = new CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider(
    getApplicationContext(), // Context
    identityProvider,
    Regions.US_EAST_1 // Region
);

AmazonS3Client sS3Client = new AmazonS3Client(cognitoCachingCredentialsProvider);
TransferUtility transferUtility = new TransferUtility(sS3Client, getApplicationContext());
```

KOIAWSAuthenticatedIdentityProvider.java

```
package com.krossover.network.aws;

import com.amazonaws.auth.AWSCognitoIdentityProvider;
import com.amazonaws.auth.IdentityChangedListener;
import com.krossover.network.models.AWSToken;

import java.util.Map;

/**
 * Created by paulshin on 9/26/16.
 */
public class KOIAWSAuthenticatedIdentityProvider implements AWSCognitoIdentityProvider {
    private AWSToken awsToken;

    public KOIAWSAuthenticatedIdentityProvider(AWSToken awsToken) {
        this.awsToken = awsToken;
    }

    @Override
    public String getIdentityId() {
        return awsToken.id;
    }

    @Override
    public String getIdentityPoolId() {
        return awsToken.identityPoolId;
    }

    @Override
    public void setLogins(Map<String, String> loginsMap) {

    }

    @Override
    public Map<String, String> getLogins() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAuthenticated() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void registerIdentityChangedListener(IdentityChangedListener listener) {

    }

    @Override
    public void unregisterIdentityChangedListener(IdentityChangedListener listener) {

    }

    @Override
    public void identityChanged(String newIdentity) {

    }

    @Override
    public void clearListeners() {

    }

    @Override
    public String getToken() {
        return awsToken.token;
    }

    @Override
    public String refresh() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

The problem is that I keep getting this ERROR

```
E/CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider: Failure to get credentials
    com.amazonaws.services.cognitoidentity.model.NotAuthorizedException: Access to Identity 'us-east-1:xxxxx' is forbidden. (Service: AmazonCognitoIdentity; Status Code: 400; Error Code: NotAuthorizedException; Request ID: xxxxx)
        at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.handleErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:712)
        at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:388)
        at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:199)
        at com.amazonaws.services.cognitoidentity.AmazonCognitoIdentityClient.invoke(AmazonCognitoIdentityClient.java:558)
        at com.amazonaws.services.cognitoidentity.AmazonCognitoIdentityClient.getCredentialsForIdentity(AmazonCognitoIdentityClient.java:388)
        at com.amazonaws.auth.CognitoCredentialsProvider.populateCredentialsWithCognito(CognitoCredentialsProvider.java:651)
        at com.amazonaws.auth.CognitoCredentialsProvider.startSession(CognitoCredentialsProvider.java:577)
        at com.amazonaws.auth.CognitoCredentialsProvider.getCredentials(CognitoCredentialsProvider.java:371)
        at com.amazonaws.auth.CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider.getCredentials(CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider.java:441)
        at com.amazonaws.auth.CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider.getCredentials(CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider.java:76)
        at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:4369)
        at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.initiateMultipartUpload(AmazonS3Client.java:3287)
        at com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.s3.transferutility.UploadTask.initiateMultipartUpload(UploadTask.java:252)
        at com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.s3.transferutility.UploadTask.uploadMultipartAndWaitForCompletion(UploadTask.java:100)
        at com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.s3.transferutility.UploadTask.call(UploadTask.java:80)
        at com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.s3.transferutility.UploadTask.call(UploadTask.java:44)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
 E/UploadTask: Error initiating multipart upload: 31 due to Access to Identity 'us-east-1:xxxxx' is forbidden. (Service: AmazonCognitoIdentity; Status Code: 400; Error Code: NotAuthorizedException; Request ID: xxxxx)
```

Our iOS app has very similar logic and it works fine and never got Access forbidden error. I don't know why I get it from Android library.

FYI, this is iOS counterpart of KOIAWSAuthenticatedIdentityProvider.java

```
class KOIAWSAuthenticatedIdentityProvider: AWSCognitoCredentialsProviderHelper {

    private var awsToken: String

    init(regionType: AWSRegionType,
         identityPoolId: String,
         providerName: String,
         identityId: String,
         token: String)
    {
        self.awsToken = token

        super.init(
            regionType: regionType,
            identityPoolId: identityPoolId,
            useEnhancedFlow: true,
            identityProviderManager: nil)

        self.identityId = identityId
    }

    override func token() -> AWSTask {
        return AWSTask(result: self.awsToken)
    }
}
```

I see the the difference is Android doesn't have anything to do with useEnhancedFlow: true"..

Anyone has any idea? Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

Access to identity x is forbidden is almost always thrown when it's an authenticated identity (one that already has a login linked to it), but a request is being made for that identity with no logins included. Cognito requires that you provide >= 1 login linked to an authenticated identity when trying to access it.

It's likely you're running into this issue as the class you're subclassing isn't the right one. Per the [Cognito docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/developer-authenticated-identities.html), you should subclass AWSAbstractCognitoDeveloperIdentityProvider.